# Пропускает всю функцию, вывод пустой

Tags: python, python-3.x

По сути он "пропускает" всю функцию, вывод пустой, но при этом ни ошибки, ничего нет. Предупреждения также отсутствуют.

```
b = int(input())
g = 0
h = 0
n = 0


def check():
    hn = False
    hu = False
    global b
    global g
    global h
    global n

    while b != 0:
        if b > g and hu is False:
            h += b
            hu = True
        if b < g and hn is False:
            n += b
            hn = True
        g = 0
        g += b
        b = int(input())

    return h, n, n - h
```

Comment: какой вывод? он у вас есть? return возвращает элементы, но никуда их не выводит, так что у вас просто отрабатывает функция, что вы прописали, без ошибок

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что Вы ее не вызвали. Напишите:

```
print(check())
```

А лучше от глобальных переменных отказаться, если они нужны только в этой ф-ции:

```
def check(b, g=0, h=0, n=0):
    hn = False
    hu = False

    while b != 0:
        if b > g and hu is False:
            h += b
            hu = True
        if b < g and hn is False:
            n += b
            hn = True
        g = 0
        g += b
        b = int(input())
    return h, n, n - h

print(check(int(input())))
```

Comment: А можно объяснить тупому мне где именно её надо вызывать?

Comment: А все не надо понял.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего проблема в том, что вы эту функцию нигде не вызываете.
Для этого в самом конце файла досточно написать `check()`
Однако лучшей практикой является

1. задание единой точки входа в приложение с помощью функции, которою принято называть `main`
2. стараться обходиться без глобальных переменных в коде

Таким образом, предлагаю следующий код

```
def check(b, g, h, n):
    hn = False
    hu = False

    while b != 0:
        if b > g and hu is False:
            h += b
            hu = True
        if b < g and hn is False:
            n += b
            hn = True
        g = 0
        g += b
        b = int(input("Введите число "))

    return h, n, n - h


def main():
    b = int(input("Введите число "))
    g = 0
    h = 0
    n = 0

    result = check(b, g, h, n)
    print(result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

И конечно, не забудьте, что программа ожидает от вас на вход число, которое вы введёте в консоль

Comment: Я думаю он сейчас обалдеет от увиденного =) Хотел 1 функцию вызвать, а тут на тебе - единую точку входа еще надо прописывать))) Сейчас бросит  python изучать (((

Answer (score 0):

Потому что чтобы функция "работала", её кто-то должен вызвать.

А ещё, в коде вообще нет вывода.

Comment: по-моему, в текущем виде тянет не более чем на комментарий. // тем более, что и сам вопрос-то, по-хорошему, надо бы закрыть, как врядли полезный кому-либо ещё.